# $ S = \left\lbrace\frac{m\sqrt{n}}{p} - 2\pi n^{3/2}p\,, \;n \in \mathbb{N}\,, m \in \mathbb{Z}\right\rbrace$ is an enumerable set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Define the following set
$$
 S = \bigg\lbrace\dfrac{m\sqrt{n}}{p} - 2\pi n^{3/2}p, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}, m \in \mathbb{Z}\bigg\rbrace
$$
where $p > 0$. I would like to show that $S$ is an enumerable set.

Since $S$ is determined by $m$ and $n$. I thought of showing that the functions
$$F_{1} : S_{n} \to \mathbb{N}, \ \ F_{2} : S_{m} \to \mathbb{Z}$$
are injective, where $S_{n}$ is the set where I fixed $m$ in $S$ and $S_{m}$ is the set where I fixed $n$ in $S$.

Therefore, $G = S_{n} \times S_{m} \to \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$
G(n,m) = (F_{1}(n),F_{2}(m))
$$
is injetive and how $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{Z}$ is an enumerable set, $S= S_{n} \times S_{m}$ is an enumerable set.

Is there a shorter argument? Is mine correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes your argument is correct (assuming $F_1, F_2$ are the natural maps that one would consider here).

Here's an alternate way (in the same spirit).

Lemma : A set $A$ is countable if there is a surjection of $\mathbb{N}$ onto $A$.

The mapping $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{N} \to S$ sending $(m,n) \mapsto \frac{m\sqrt{n}}{p} - 2\pi n^{3/2}p$ is clearly surjective.

Further, there is a bijection of $\mathbb{N}$ onto $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{N}$.

Take the composite. Done.

Comment: Thank you very much.